# How to fix ErrorException: @OA\Items() is required when @OA\Property() has type "array"?

Tags: php, openapi, swagger-php

I've tried to add a nested array of arbitrary types.
These are my annotations:

```
* @OA\Property(
*      @OA\Schema(
*          type="array",
*          @OA\Items(
*              type="array",
*              @OA\Items(type={})
*          )
*      ),
*      description="bla bla bla"
* )
```

Comment: What if you replace `@OA\Items(type={})` with `@OA\Items()`?

Comment: I've already tried that, it doesn't work

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
 * @OA\Property(
 *      type="array",
 *      @OA\Items(
 *          type="array",
 *          @OA\Items()
 *      ),
 *      description="bla bla bla"
 * )
```

The issue was @OA\Schema

Comment: Thanks, this really helped!

Comment: how we can set required for a field?

Comment: *     @OA\Parameter(
     *          name="",
     *          in="path",
     *          @OA\Schema(type="string"),
     *          required=true,
     *          description=""
     *     ),

Comment: its worth also mentioning, that for this to work and not throw an error, the description field must be after the items, not before, as in the answers example.